# VCL-Styles embedded in dll?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

How do I embed Delphi XE2 VCL-Styles in a dll? The Application - Appearance page is not visible in project settings for DLL-projects.

I tried defining them in a rc-file included with a $R directive which works but if there is a better way I'd like to know.

RC-file example:

```
GOLDENGRAPHITE VCLSTYLE "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\Redist\styles\vcl\GoldenGraphite.vsf"
CARBON VCLSTYLE "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\Redist\styles\vcl\Carbon.vsf"
```

In particular having to specify the full path to XE2-installation folder is something I want to avoid.

Comment: You could do the same using Project Resource dialog. Also, RC is happy with relative paths.

Comment: Also be aware that you will need to disable system hooks in a DLL as there is no Mainform, otherwise you'll get Access Violations:

TStyleManager.SystemHooks := [];
TStyleManager.TrySetStyle(StyleName);

Comment: Yes you can put the vsf files anywhere you like and enter a relative path to the rc file's folder. I recommend a common folder for both rc and vsfs that all your DLLs and exe code can access. If you use the rc in your exe, you'll have to remove the Style from the exe Options or you will get an error for setting it twice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another options which you can use

1) Using the  Resource dialog.

[image]

2) Editing the dproj file of your dll

under this key `<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Base)'!=''">`

Add one Entry `VCL_Custom_Styles` for the vcl styles

```
<VCL_Custom_Styles>&quot;Amakrits|VCLSTYLE|$(PUBLIC)\Documents\RAD Studio\9.0\Styles\Amakrits.vsf&quot;;&quot;Amethyst Kamri|VCLSTYLE|$(PUBLIC)\Documents\RAD Studio\9.0\Styles\AmethystKamri.vsf&quot;;&quot;Aqua Graphite|VCLSTYLE|$(PUBLIC)\Documents\RAD Studio\9.0\Styles\AquaGraphite.vsf&quot;</VCL_Custom_Styles>
```

Comment: Thanks, never noticed the resource dialog before. Both suggestions are good.

Comment: I've added the resource, it's in my cbproj as:      
<RcItem Include="C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\Redist\styles\vcl\Amakrits.vsf">
<ContainerId>ResourceItem</ContainerId>
<ResourceType>VCLSTYLE</ResourceType>
<ResourceId>AMAKRITS</ResourceId>
Now how to access it dynamically? I tried TStyleManager::SetStyle but it throws an exception that the style cannot be found. Do I need to do anything else?

Answer (score 1):

It works for us also (thanks Rodrigo). Just a couple of details

- Don't expect to find the VCLSTYLE on the list  of the Resource Type Combo Box, you have to type it manually.
- Don't miss to initialize the style in your DLL, we add the next code to the FormCreate event:
  *TStyleManager.SetStyle('Carbon');*

Answer (score 0):

To access correctly to the Style added as a resource check you are adding to the uses clause both units: Vcl.Themes, Vcl.Styles.