# How to manually include a VCL Style in my application?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

I have an application which uses conditionals to be able to compile it either as a VCL Forms Application or as a Windows Service Application in Delphi XE2. However, since I have manually altered the project's main source file, the IDE will no longer allow me to make certain modifications using the standard Project Options window. Specifically, I am not able to select VCL Styles to include or implement.

Therefore, I have to implement VCL Styles manually. So, I added the two necessary units `Vcl.Themes` and `Vcl.Styles` to my project's initialization unit (which in this case is NOT the same as the project's main unit), and essentially copied the code from a working application into this new application.

Here's the project's main unit:

```
program MyServiceApplication;

uses
  uMyService in 'uMyService.pas' {MyService: TService},
  uMyServiceMain in 'uMyServiceMain.pas',
  uMyServiceInit in 'uMyServiceInit.pas',
  uMyServiceTest in 'uMyServiceTest.pas' {frmMyServiceTest};

{$R *.RES}

begin
  RunMyService;
end.
```

And then in the project's initialization unit:

```
unit uMyServiceInit;

interface

uses
{$IFDEF TESTAPP}
  Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.Themes,
  Vcl.Styles,
  uMyServiceTest,
{$ELSE}
  Vcl.SvcMgr,
  uMyService,
{$ENDIF TESTAPP}
  uMyServiceMain
  ;

procedure RunMyService;

implementation

procedure RunMyService;
begin
{$IFDEF TESTAPP}
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Carbon'); //<--- WILL NOT RUN - STYLE DOES NOT EXIST
  Application.Title := 'My Windows Service Application';
  Application.CreateForm(TfrmMyServiceTest, frmMyServiceTest);
{$ELSE}
  if not Application.DelayInitialize or Application.Installing then
    Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TMyService, MyService);
{$ENDIF TESTAPP}
  Application.Run;
end;

end.
```

The trouble is, when the application runs, I get an error `Style 'Carbon' could not be found.` simply because this style has not been included and compiled into the application.

How can I compile this style manually into this application so that the VCL Styles can implement it?

PS: The reason why the initialization is in a separate unit is because if the conditionals were implemented inside the application's main unit, the IDE would *destroy* the code.

**EDIT**

One thing I have tried: I opened a working project's `.dproj` file and searched for this style `carbon` hoping to find some configuration for it there, since the working project used this style, but with no luck. The word does not exist anywhere in that file.

Comment: From a quick check with `Resource Editor`, it appears that the styles are added to a resource as `VCLSTYLE` resource type. This seems to imply you could create a standard `.rc` file with a list of the style files (the `.vsf` files from the `$(BDS)\Redist\Styles\Vcl` folder). I haven't had a chance to test it yet, though. You may also have to register the styles with the style manager in code as well.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use project->resources&images to add carbon.vsf with ID=CARBON, type=VCLSTYLE.

Comment: Eureka, thanks @Sertac, that's the best solution I think.

Comment: Jerry, @Ken's method should also work, the only difference is that you add some 'some.rc' file to the project with project manager and then add a line {$R some.res}.

Comment: @JerryDodge, this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703309/vcl-styles-embedded-in-dll) shows how add vcl styles manually using the  Resource dialog or editing the `.dproj` file

Comment: https://delphiaball.co.uk/2014/10/22/adding-vcl-styles-runtime/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`TStyleManager` is loading available styles from a 'VCLSTYLE' resource section of the executable (unless you set `TStyleManager.AutoDiscoverStyleResources` to false). The resource is what's missing in your scenario.
 Basically, there are three ways to add your style as a resource in the exe.

- Through the 'Project' -> 'Resources and Images..' menu. Add the style clicking the 'Add' button in the dialog, set its type to 'VCLSTYLE' and identifier to 'CARBON'.
- As [Ken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62576/ken-white) mentioned in the comment to the question, through an .rc file. This is a text file which can contain a line per style (and/or other resources). Like`CARBON VCLSTYLE "C:\..\RAD Studio\9.0\Redist\Styles\Vcl\Carbon.vsf"`
  (you can use relative paths if it is feasible). Let's name the file 'styles.rc', add the file to the project through project manager (or use brcc32.exe in the bin folder to compile it to a .res file) and then add a `{$R styles.res}` line to your unit.
- As [RRUZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91299/rruz) told in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9704000/243614) that he linked in a comment to the question, by editing the .dproj file. Under the `<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Base)'!=''">` key, add a `VCL_Custom_Styles` entry (his example includes several styles):
  `<VCL_Custom_Styles>&quot;Amakrits|VCLSTYLE|$(PUBLIC)\Documents\RAD Studio\9.0\Styles\Amakrits.vsf&quot;;&quot;Amethyst Kamri|VCLSTYLE|$(PUBLIC)\Documents\RAD Studio\9.0\Styles\AmethystKamri.vsf&quot;;&quot;Aqua Graphite|VCLSTYLE|$(PUBLIC)\Documents\RAD Studio\9.0\Styles\AquaGraphite.vsf&quot;</VCL_Custom_Styles>`

Comment: +1. Nice answer, Sertac. (And you even got a "Thank you" from Jerry in the comemnts, too. More than I got. ;-)

Comment: I actually prefer it, because it makes it much easier to add/remove things like styles (if you can't do it using `Project->Options`). It's really easy to open the text `.rc` file and comment out or add a line, save, and then build the project to make the changes take effect. It's quicker than using the resource dialog. :-)

Comment: I've written plenty of `.rc` files but I never realized there was a quick menu item to add resources.

Comment: For the .rc file approach, note that the asterisk in `{$R *.res}` is not a wildcard. Instead, it seems to mean: load a .res file named like the project, e.g. "project1.res". You definitely need to load another .res file explicitely: `{$R styles.res}`

Answer (score 0):

1. Put '*.vsf' of selected style file in .exe dir.
2. In .dpr add/change

   ```
   ...
   var 
      str_stylefile:ansistring;
      int_style_count:integer;
    ...
    begin
   Application.Initialize;
   str_stylefile:=ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'EmeraldLightSlate.vsf';//for example
   if FileExists(str_stylefile) then
   begin
   TStyleManager.LoadFromFile(str_stylefile);
   if length(TStyleManager.StyleNames)>1 then
      TStyleManager.TrySetStyle(TStyleManager.StyleNames[1]);//0-Windows style(defaut),1 - loaded style
   end;
   ...
   Application.Run;
   end.
   ```
3. Copmile/Run.