# How to add a VCL Style to an old Delphi 7 project migrated to Delphi XE7?

Tags: delphi, interface, vcl

Years ago, I made a program in Delphi 7, which uses a basic interface. It looks like a Windows XP application.

[image]

I want to apply one of the VCL Styles available in Delphi XE7, but after migrating the project and selecting a Style, it does not dress up the application.

[image]

Comment: Look down below at "Default style" - make sure you change that. Checking them only includes/compiles them with your project. You need to actually switch it to the one you want to use. This is because you can also switch between the compiled styles during runtime.

Comment: Go to _Application_ node and check there _Enable Runtime Themes_ check box. After that, go back to this page and select _Carbon_ from the _Default style_ combo box.

Comment: Are you migrating a Delphi 7 project to the XE7 IDE? Because Delphi 7 does not support VCL Styles at all (they didn't exist yet at the time). It doesn't even support XP Visual Themes either, you have to use a third party component ([Soft Gems XP Theme Manager](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/controls/windows-xp-theme-manager)) to enable that. That component was integrated into the VCL around Delphi 8.

Comment: @JerryDodge I tried it, but [link](http://prntscr.com/i9xzkl) Style Carbon not found

Comment: @Victoria _Enable Runtime Themes_ it's allready checked, I switched to the _Carbon_ from the _Default style_ combo box and has the same result

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes I am migrating from D7 to XE7; Is there a way that I can use one of these VCL Styles without recoding everything again? I wouldn't like my application looks like a Windows XP program. Sorry for my delay, yesterday without internet..

Comment: Of course you won't need to re-code everything. You'll just need to understand how VCL Styles works, and make sure your project has everything it needs set up to use them. This might help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574234/how-to-manually-include-a-vcl-style-in-my-application

Comment: Adding the res.rc file with `CARBON VCLSTYLE "C:\..\RAD Studio\9.0\Redist\Styles\Vcl\Carbon.vsf"` worked for me, Thanks, you can answer this question with that.