# Delphi - Appearance not visible in the project options

Tags: delphi

I have a problem that in one of my projects I cannot add themes since the menu item for

Application (Anwendung)

|_ Appearance (Erscheinungsbild)

is not visible.
[image]
[image]

It happens only in my main project.
In new projects it is visible.

Any idea how I can let that item (re)appear?

I am using Delphi 10.2.3

Solution:
Nil & Jerry gave me the right ideas.
I had `Application.CreateForm`moved to another unit. 
And this was the reason why Delphi didn't show me the options.

Comment: What are the respective project types? For example a Console Application will not have Appearance in the project options.

Comment: I'm not really sure if it matters, but did you originally develop the main project with an earlier version of Delphi. Which one in that case?

Comment: This can happen if you've manually altered your `dpr` file, in such a way that the IDE can no longer interpret what type of project you have. In such a case, you will have to do such things manually. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574234/how-to-manually-include-a-vcl-style-in-my-application

Comment: The project was developed originally with Delphi 7 and went through 2006, 2010, XE2, XE6, XE7, XE8, Seattle, Berlin and now Tokyo. I never cared for themes till now. So I was surprised not to be able to add some

Comment: @ nil & @Jerry: you gave me the right ideas. I altered the dpr and moved Application.CreateForm to another unit. When I move it back then 'Appearances' is visible again.