# VCL-Style Issues in DLL

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

I have developed a DLL having one form. I have set a style to it using below code.

```
library TestLib;

uses Vcl.Themes, Vcl.Styles,....
.
.
exports
   function1,
   function2;

begin
   TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Style1');
end.
```

When I load this dll and call function1 which opens this form. Form gets open with style applied to it.

Now I am getting an access violation when I minimize that window. Everything including Maximize & Restore is working fine. Also All the functionality are working fine.

I guess it is not handling message generated by Minimize event of this form. Please advice.

**Note:** When I remove style, everything is working fine.

```
Call Stack

:0976742b TWinControl.HandleNeeded + $3
:0978ad8a TStyleManager.HandleMessage + $56
:09762a3c TWinControl.DoHandleStyleMessage + $14
:0972e6be TCustomForm.WndProc + $612
:09763c2b TWinControl.MainWndProc + $2F
```

**UPDATE : SSCCE**

Project1.EXE (having one form Unit1.pas/dfm)

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    function InitDLL: Boolean;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

const
   cLIBRARY = 'Project2.dll';

var
   DLLHandle : THandle;
   showfrm: procedure;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   if InitDLL then
      showfrm;
end;

function TForm1.InitDLL: Boolean;
begin
   if DLLHandle = 0 then
   begin
      DLLHandle := LoadLibrary(PChar(cLIBRARY));
      if DLLHandle <> 0 then
      begin
         @showfrm := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'showfrm');
      end
      else
      begin
         Result := False;
         raise Exception.Create('Error loading DLL: ' + cLIBRARY);
      end;
   end;

   Result := (DLLHandle > 0);
end;

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

create one DLL Project2.dll having unit2 as any form and unit3 which will invoke that form.
Add a style (say AnyStyle1) to this dll as resource.

```
library Project2;

{ Important note about DLL memory management: ShareMem must be the
  first unit in your library's USES clause AND your project's (select
  Project-View Source) USES clause if your DLL exports any procedures or
  functions that pass strings as parameters or function results. This
  applies to all strings passed to and from your DLL--even those that
  are nested in records and classes. ShareMem is the interface unit to
  the BORLNDMM.DLL shared memory manager, which must be deployed along
  with your DLL. To avoid using BORLNDMM.DLL, pass string information
  using PChar or ShortString parameters. }

{$R *.dres}

uses
  ShareMem,
  Vcl.Themes,
  Vcl.Styles,
  Vcl.Dialogs,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Form2},
  Unit3 in 'Unit3.pas';

{$R *.res}

exports
showfrm;

begin
   if TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('AnyStyle1') then
   begin
      ShowMessage('True');
   end
   else
      ShowMessage('False');
end.
```

unit3.pas

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses Unit2;

   procedure showfrm;

implementation
   procedure showfrm;
   begin
      with TForm2.Create(nil) do
         Show;
   end;
end.
```

Now press minimize button of Unit2 window. You will get an access violation.

Comment: Dude - why not check for "if not TStyleManager.TrySetStyle()"?  Where's your error detection/error handling???  ALSO: You typically set up a custom style in the IDE.  This might do some implicit "initialization".  It sounds like the style manager hasn't been correctly initialized the way you're doing it.  IMHO...  Check out [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906312/delphi-xe2-vcl-styles-tutorial-how-to-change-the-style-at-runtime).

Comment: @paulsm4 : In this link also similar code is written. TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Style1'); Configuration using IDE (Project Option) can be done for EXE only. This option of setting style is not available for DLL.

Comment: Possible duplicate [`VCL-Styles embedded in dll?`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9703309/576719)

Comment: @Dev - my point is that the IDE does a lot of stuff "under the covers" that *wouldn't* necessarily happen if you're making calls from a .dll.  I strongly suspect that important initialization hasn't happened.  Having said that: if "TrySetStyle()" returns a boolean (i.e. if it can fail) ... then it behooves you to CHECK for "false".  IMHO...

Comment: @LURD - I have gone through your link. I have done same thing to add a style in DLL. Only one issue I am facing here as mentioned above.

Comment: @paulsm4 - I have checked return value for this operation and it is returning TRUE.

Comment: This could be a bug. I added the Vcl-Styles tag to the question so that people watching this can respond (@RRUZ for example).

Comment: Very likely the problem is the usual one of sharing VCL objects across DLL boundary. Show a full SSCCE.

Comment: Sine many people don't know what `SSCCE` means: [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable VCL styles in Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598728/how-to-disable-vcl-styles-in-delphi)

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers If people are incapable of typing SSCCE into a websearch then they may as well give up programming

Comment: @AdamArold - I have only one form in my DLL and I don't want to disable VCL style for it. Instead I have applied it and working great except this one issue.

Comment: Updated Description to add a working example of this issue.

Comment: +1 Your SSCCE is good and I can confirm the behaviour. No idea why yet......

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it might be that an abbreviation means something different to them, or they do not recognize it even if the context is perfectly clear to you. The first time I had the impression SSCCE was something about some system software configuration control engine. Don't get me started on SOA...

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers I'm not about to start explaining SSCCE every time I use it. As I said, if somebody is incapable of typing SSCCE into a websearch and clicking on the top hit, then they are not in the right business

Comment: I am trying hard to understand how this question might be a duplicate of " How to disable VCL styles in Delphi ". .. and failing at that..

Comment: Boy am I glad Jon Skeet is more friendly to the SO users: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22762/137204 "Please provide a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason of the access violation is that, vcl styles in Delphi XE2 does not seem to be designed with VCL styles in a dll in mind. The AV is thrown in the `WM_SIZE` handler of the form style hook:

```
procedure TFormStyleHook.WMSize(var Message: TWMSize);
begin
  if IsIconic(Handle) and (Application.MainForm.Handle <> Handle) then
    InvalidateNC;

  ...
```

The style hook tests if the message is being handled on the main form, but there's no main form in a dll. Accessing the handle of the unassigned reference causes the exception.

The below workaround introduces a descendant style hook to prevent this, it bypasses the check for the main form and lets the processing of the message continue at `TWinControl`.

This is the entire, modified 'unit3' in the dll:

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses forms, messages, themes, windows, Unit2;

procedure showfrm;

implementation

type
  TForm2StyleHook = class(TFormStyleHook)
  private
    procedure WMSize(var Message: TWMSIZE); message WM_SIZE;
  end;

procedure TForm2StyleHook.WMSize(var Message: TWMSIZE);
begin
  if IsIconic(Handle) then begin
    // duplicate the code in ascendant, for whatever it serves
    InvalidateNC;
    // the rest of the code in ascendant class is related with MDI

    Handled := False; // if this is set to true TWinControl.WndProc returns
  end else
    inherited;
end;

procedure showfrm;
begin
  TStyleManager.Engine.RegisterStyleHook(TForm2, TForm2StyleHook);

  with TForm2.Create(nil) do
    Show;
end;

end.
```

Note also the possibility of continuing to hit issues like these while considering to use styles in a dll.

Comment: Note to @Dev: While this code solves that particular bug, VCL-in-dll has lots of others, not only styles-related.

Answer (score 0):

You should compile bouth dll and exe in the same version of RAD Studio with "Runtime packages" enabled. Only in this case form in dll is guaranteed to work properly.

Comment: That does not in fact look like an issue with the SSCCE presented

Comment: That's exactly the issue I had a couple years ago with another skinning engine. VCL behaves badly in dll and skins make all these bugs visible.

Comment: Well, it could be that I suppose. A more subtle manifestation of the usual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Styles are getting more popular, so maybe it'll help future readers, especially since the AV on minimize is still there with Delphi RIO 10.3.3.

I found out that creating a dummy hidden mainform in the dll helps.

Just pass the application object to the dll and do this inside

```
var
  aMainForm: TForm;
begin
      Application.Handle := App.Handle;
      Application.OnIdle := App.OnIdle;
      Application.OnMessage := App.OnMessage;
      Application.CreateForm(TForm, aMainForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

In DLLs, system hooks must be turned off before calling SetStyle in DLLs, otherwise it will try to access a Mainform that does not exist and you'll get Access Violations, etc.

```
TStyleManager.SystemHooks := [];
TStyleManager.SetStyle(StyleName);
```

It took me a long time to find this out, it needs to be more widely documented, hence this post.